# How and when to call LoadRequest with postdata in CEFSharp in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, postdata

I need to do a LoadRequest(request) with postdata in CEFSharp.  I was using the IE Navigate but wanting to switch over to CEFSharp so I found a Navigate function for CEFSharp.

```
public void Navigate (string url, byte[] postDataBytes, string contentType)
{
    IFrame frame = eRXWebBrowser.GetMainFrame ();
    IRequest request = frame.CreateRequest (initializePostData: true);

    request.Url = url;
    request.Method = "POST";

    //request.InitializePostData ();
    var element = request.PostData.CreatePostDataElement ();
    element.Bytes = postDataBytes;
    var status = request.PostData.AddElement (element);

    NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"Content-Type", contentType}
    };
    request.Headers = headers;

    frame.LoadRequest (request);
}
```

I call this in the Load event for the ViewModel but nothing happens.  I feel like I am close but just missing something.  Cannot find info on when to call the LoadRequest().  I am using CEFSharp version 65 and I have tried loading a webpage before the Load event and the webpage shows fine.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The framework already provides an extension method that does the same thing see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/5adff7014b2de86d6afbf9e2b0707283336f02c1/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L236

Comment: See http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16058&p=38563&hilit=LoadRequest#p38559